# Copias de seguridad en laravel con Spatie desde un controlador no funciona en windows

Tags: laravel, spatie

Estoy probando Spatie para crear copia de seguridad desde un controlador y solo funciona cuando intento crear copia únicamente de los archivos, pero si intento crear copia de base de datos ocurre un error.
Sin embargo desde una consola sí se crea correctamente la copia de los archivos y de la base de datos.

Pienso que puede ser por no tener acceso a mysqldum.exe o algo así, ya que al principio no lograba crear copias de seguridad desde la consola hasta que agregué la ruta a mysqldump.exe a las variables de entorno.

Estoy utilizando Windows y XAMPP para desarrollo.

Alguien tiene una idea de cuál es el problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]